# Group data by Namespace in memcache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

In one of our application we want to store different type of objects in Memcache server using dalli client.

One type of data is to store rails session value which needs to be flushed when user log out.
Another set of data is some objects which we need to flush after every 15mins.

We are able to store Rails session in Memcache server using following code
Rails.application.config.session_store ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore, :expire_after => 20.minutes

But if we try to flush our Memcache data after 15mins my session also gets clear.
Is it possible to separate and clear objects based on namespace.

Regards,

Nidhi Sarvaiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per response received from dalli gem github tracker it is not possible to group by namespace.